# Angular 2.0 router.navigate not working

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2.0 with router version 3.0.0. I have following routing configuration defined.

```
export const onlineRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'online.html', component:onlineHome },
 { path: 'portfolioperformance', component: PortfolioPerformance },
];

 export const onlinerouting = RouterModule.forRoot(onlineRoutes,{useHash:false,enableTracing:true});
```

It routes successfully to online.html route however when I try to route to 'portfolioperformance' using following statement it doesn't work.

```
this.router.navigate(['/portfolioperformance']);
```

If I use router link like below, on clicking on link it works fine.

```
<li><a [router-link]="['/portfolioperformance']">Start</a></li>
```

I enabled router tracing and following are route trace details.

```
‹Start group›: Router Event: NavigationStart
    NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/portfolioperformance')
    NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/portfolioperformance"}
‹End group›
‹Start group›: Router Event: NavigationStart
    NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/online.html#id_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
‹End group›
 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
 ‹Start group›: Router Event: NavigationCancel
    NavigationCancel(id: 1, url: '/portfolioperformance')
    NavigationCancel {id: 1, url: "/portfolioperformance", reason: "Navigation ID 1 is not equal to the current navigation id 2"}
 ‹End group›
 ‹Start group›: Router Event: RoutesRecognized
    RoutesRecognized(id: 2, url: '/online.html#id_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'online.html', path:'online.html') } )
```

Couldn't figure out whats going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `this.router.navigate(...), {relativeTo: currentRoute});`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but didn't help.

Comment: You have tried `routerLink` and `this.router.navigate` in the same component and you passed `constructor(this currentRoute:ActivatedRotue)` to `relativeTo`? (see also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#relative-navigation)

Comment: Yeah I injected currentRoute:ActivatedRoute in constructor but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: Sorry, you shouldn't need it anyway, because it's an absolute path, because of the `/` at the beginning.

Comment: Have you solved this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: I am also having this issue.  routerLink works, but navigate and navigateByUrl do nothing.  The success callback calls every time.  However, I have noted that if I put some random URL in the call, it also returns the success handler, so I guess that's useless, here.